# Implementing K-Means Algorithm JDBC

Tags: java, sql, data-mining, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am working with an Oracle Database and have the following code implemented in java (with an SQL imported library), where I have a group of students, their average, and I flag those students with an average that is higher than one standard deviation away from the mean (by inserting a new column with a "1" in it). Then I count the number of students who meet the criteria and add them to a new table:

```
try{
         Statement stOne, stTwo, stThree, stFour;
         String SelectAverage = "SELECT MEAN FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsOne = stOne.executeQuery(SelectAverage);

    String TotalAverage = "SELECT Avg(MEAN) AS averages FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsTwo = stTwo.executeQuery(TotalAverage);     

          String student_stan_dev = "SELECT STDEV(MEAN) AS standardDeviation FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsThree = stThree.executeQuery(student_stan_dev);

           int onesdMean = 1;


           //Loop Duration_Sec column
           while(rsOne.next()){

           //Convert values into float values
           float allAvgs = rsOne.getFloat("MEAN");
           float totalAvg = rsTwo.getFloat("averages"); 
           float StDev = rsThree.getFloat("standardDeviation");

           float theSD = allAvgs - (onesdMean * StDev);
           }

        String flaggedStudents = "ALTER TABLE STUDENTS ADD FlaggedStudents INT";
        ResultSet rsFour = stFour.executeUpdate(flaggedStudents);

           if(allAvgs >= theSD){
               String FlagHint = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS.FlaggedStudents VALUES('1')";
               st.executeUpdate(FlagHint);
           }

        String countInstances = "SELECT STUDENTS.NAME, STUDENTS.FlaggedStudents" +
                "COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENTS) AS cnt FROM STUDENTS";
           st.executeQuery(countInstances);


        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentCount" +
        "(NAME INT , cnt INT)");

        String insertVals = String.format("INSERT INTO StudentCount" +
                "(NAME , cnt INT") +
                " VALUES ('%s','%s')");

        st.execute(insertVals);
```

My question is, I want to implement a k-means algorithm instead, to cluster students who meet this criteria and separate those who are far from meeting this criteria. I have seen source code for the k-means algorithm, but how would I go about doing that with a database implemented in java/SQL? Would I just add this information to a cluster array? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one attribute, choose a different algorithm than k-means.

Clustering algorithms are really only good for multidimensional data.

For one-dimensional data, use kernel density estimation to find local minima to split the data there. This produces much more meaningful splits. And at the same time, 1-dimensional data can be sorted (and sorting is something your SQL database does very well), which makes the problem substantially easier than in multiple dimensions.

Seriously. 1-dimensional data is the prime domain of classic statistics. They have excellent tools for this kind of data, so use them!

Multi-dimensional data, where it gets tricky to accelerate your computations, is where data-mining really shines. Once the problem gets too hard to handle with proper statistics in reasonable time, THEN the heuristic approaches of data mining are attractive. But before that, classic statistics is much more clever and advanced.